# Replace console output where output length differs

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I have a program that searches thru files in a given repository to check if they contain a string...

```
print("Searching files for string...")
for folder, dirs, files in os.walk(some_path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".st") or file.endswith(".jsp"):
            fullpath = os.path.join(folder, file)

            # print fullpath
            print(fullpath, end="\r", flush=True)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            # end print fullpath                

            with open(fullpath, 'r') as read_file:
                for (line_number, line) in enumerate(read_file):
                    if search_term in line:
                        results_array.append({
                            "filepath": fullpath,
                            "line": line_number + 1
                        })
```

I want to print the fullpath to the console but replace the line, rather than the console becoming chock full of output as the loop iterates. With the current code, after a few iterations, the output starts to merge with previous lines, I'm presuming this is because the size of the paths differs on each iteration.

e.g. output with current code: 
    /somepath/example/hello-world.jspfirm.jspidgetsconfig.jsppjspdeals.jsp

How can I fix this so each fullpath gets printed and removed cleanly?

Comment: `print(fullpath, end="\r\n", flush=True)`. That should work

Comment: Doesn't work, this just makes each output have its own line

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? What does _printed cleanly_ mean?